# Trying to get subtotals from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, crosstab, subtotal

I'm doing cross-tabulation between two columns in the dataframe. Here's a sample from the columns:

```
 column_1    column_2

    A          -8
    B          95
    A         -93
    D          11
    C         -62
    D         -14
    A         -55
    C          66
    B          76
    D         -49
```

I'm looking for a code that returns sub totals for A, B, C and D. For instance, for A the subtotal will be -156 (-8-93-55 = -156).

I tried to do that with `pandas.crosstab()` function:

```
pandas.crosstab(df[column_1], df[column_2], margins=True, margins_name=column_1).Total
```

Here's a sample of the output:

```
     -271  -263  -241  -223  -221  -212  -207  -201 ...   sum_column
A      1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0  ...      ##
B      0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0  ...      ##
C      0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1  ...      ##
D      0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0  ...      ##
```

The sum column consists of the sums of the boolean values in each row, instead of the sub totals for each of the four letters. I saw once that a boolean table can be used for calculations but I quite sure that by changing the `pandas.crosstab()` command the desired output can be achieved.

I'd be happy to get some ideas and thoughts from you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd simply like the totals by the individual categories in `column_1` (A, B, C, D), maybe a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and summation could be helpful! You would call the `groupby` on the column with your categories, and then call sum on the result, like this:

```py
df.groupby('column1').sum()
```